# PostgreSQL refuse connection

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, replication

I'm deploying two servers with two PostgreSQL databases (one Primary and one Standby model). I have set the `pg_hba.conf` on my primary server to

```
host    replication    replicator    <my standby ip addr>    md5
```

and I've also enable the listen_address settings in `postgresql.conf`

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

But when I was trying to run this command on my standby server

```
pg_basebackup -h <primary server ip addr> -D /var/lib/postgresql/12/main -U replicator -P -v -R -X stream -C -S node2
```

it returned this error message

```
pg_basebackup: error: could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "<primary ip addr>" and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432
```

It is also verified that access to port 5432 has been enabled since I am able to connect to it from pgadmin via SSH.

my server is running on Ubuntu 20.04 with Postgresql version 12 installed

Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: The IP address is wrong, or you didn't restart PostgreSQL after changing `listen_addresses`, or you got the wrong port, or there is a network or firewall problem.

Comment: Verifying that works over an SSH tunnel doesn't help show that it works without an SSH tunnel.

Comment: It happened to be the port problem, turns out that I allow connection on port 5432 without specifying tcp connection for that port.